# is it a good idea to put expired tokens to blacklist table?

Tags: jwt, refresh-token

To begin with this is how my current auth flow looks

1. User logs in

   2. User gets a refresh_token assigned and stored in the database (long lived 7d)
   3. Client receives an accestoken (Short lived, 2h), and stores it as a cookie. Client also receives the userId AES encrypted, and stores
      it as a cookie.
   4. As far as the access token is not expired, the user keeps using the token to navigate the website
   5. The token expires
   6. The expired access token gets send to a refresh endpoint, so is the userID (Aes encrypted) both currently stored in out cookies.
   7. The server decrypts the userId and retrieves the refreshtoken that corresponds to the user by selecting the refresh token from the database using out userId.
   8. Now we have in the server our refreshtoken and accestoken, so we refresh the token, and send back the new accesstoken. We also generate a new refreshtoken and overwrite our old refreshtoken in the database with the new one.

My question is basically related to that last step. Since those refresh tokens are still technically valid, since they have a long expiration time. Can I create a table in my database named "blacklisted_tokens" or something like that, and store there the values of the token? And then right before generating a new access token it should prior to that check if that refresh token is or isnt in that database, meaning that it will be blacklisted.

This is the authflow diagram
[image]

Comment: It won't possible in jwt token authentication.  May  be its possible in oauth tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is basically related to that last step. Since those
>   refresh tokens are still technically valid, since they have a long
>   expiration time. Can I create a table in my database named
>   "blacklisted_tokens" or something like that, and store there the
>   values of the token? And then right before generating a new access
>   token it should prior to that check if that refresh token is or isnt
>   in that database, meaning that it will be blacklisted.

it's not recommended to do that as because, probability of generating 2 same token is low and adding **NOT** necessary additional processes to your back-end is not a good idea and has performance issue in large scale Token re-generation(a lot of users).

And also, Tokens are along with an identity(id) in which reduces security risks.

if i were you, i would just re-write new-token to old-token.

The most important type of cyber attack which threaten Tokens is The [Sniffing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sniffing_attack) and by doing below steps actually the probability of this attack goes almost to zero:

- SSL certificate
- Expiring Token and re-generation
- Salty requests

### Salt

> In cryptography, a salt is random data that is used as an additional
>   input to a one-way function that hashes data, a password or
>   passphrase. Salts are used to safeguard passwords in storage.